# Adding a dynamic member to an ExpandoObject

Tags: vb.net, expandoobject

In the following method I am trying to add a dynamic member to an expando object but it throws an exception:

> public member not found for expand object

```
Private Sub GetAckValues()
    Try
        Dim ack_duration As String = String.Empty
        Dim ack_by_user_fkid As String = String.Empty
        Dim ack_time As String = String.Empty
        ack_duration = txtdefaultack.Text
        ack_by_user_fkid = Convert.ToString(Session("user_code"))
        Dim Ack_Detail As Object = New ExpandoObject()
        Ack_Detail.ack_duration = ack_duration
        Ack_Detail.ack_by_user_fkid = ack_by_user_fkid 
        receiptObject.StatusObject = Ack_Detail
     Catch ex As Exception
        logger.Error("Enter JobRequest form done by :" & LoggedinUserId, ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Should this:

```
Ack_Detail.ack_duration = Ack_Detail.ack_duration
```

actually be this:

```
Ack_Detail.ack_duration = ack_duration
```